# Javascript inside webview doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have a webview that displays a very simple remote webpage which has a script tag with alert in it. For some reason it doesn't show the alert when I run my app.

I've set setJavaScriptEnabled to true:

```
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

here is my html on my server:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    Welcome!
    <script>
        alert('123');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set a [WebChromeClient](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebChromeClient.html), which can handle alerts:

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```